# Is it possible to change the content HTML5 alert messages?

Tags: html

Is it possible to control HTML5 alert messages? when adding 'required' to an input field.

because I want it to be specific and I don't want it's language to depend on the browsers.

```
<input id="answer" required>
```

Comment: Please post some code demonstrating what you're trying to do, or what you've attempted to do. It's not quite clear what you want. What do you mean by "control"?

Comment: @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas I updated my question, hope it's clear now

Comment: @bwheeler96 the question above.

Comment: Thanks, I removed my downvote

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you guys for the help,

When I asked at first I didn't think it's even possible, but after your answers I googled and found this amazing tutorial:

http://blog.thomaslebrun.net/2011/11/html-5-how-to-customize-the-error-message-for-a-required-field/#.UsNN1BYrh2M

Answer (score 2):

You can use `customValidity`

```
$(function(){
    var elements = document.getElementsByTagName("input");
    for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
        elements[i].oninvalid = function(e) {
            e.target.setCustomValidity("This can't be left blank!");
        };
    }
});
```

I think that will work on at least Chrome and FF, I'm not sure about other browsers

Comment: I don't believe safari supports the HTML5 error message.

Comment: does this code work without jquery?

Comment: Yeah, I just use that instead of onLoad

Answer (score 0):

Yes:

```
<input required title="Enter something OR ELSE." />
```

The `title` attribute will be used to notify the user of a problem.

Comment: It used to be supported. But not so much anymore.